# Weird behaviour of a webpage with different resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on the main page of this website: http://liteclock.com
When the user clicks "Press to set alarm" a dialog (avgrund.js dialog) is opened for them,
on my screen it looks good but when I change the resolution to a smaller resolution, sometimes the dialog jumps halfway after the top of the window,

I've tried to debug it - viewed the difference with the CSS of the dialog or the body nad html tags - everything is the same. I really don't know what's causing this problem and I have no idea how to debug it.

I use Avgrund for the dialog box: http://lab.hakim.se/avgrund/

**EDIT**
The dialog and the bug is live on http://www.liteclock.com , you can reproduce it by pressing "Press to set alarm" and playing with the window height until the jump happens.
My resolution - 1920 x 1080 - Everything looks fine:
[image: My resolution - 1920 x 1080 - Everything looks fine]

Smaller resolution - 1280 x 720 - Same CSS, whole different look, this also happens AFTER it was ok in the beginning, it just suddenly "jumps":

[image: Smaller resolution - 1280 x 720 - Same CSS, whole different look, this also happens AFTER it was ok in the beginning, it just suddenly "jumps"]

Comment: What does the CSS properties of the dialog box give when it's opened? It's going to be dynamically set to centre in the page I'm guessing.. ?

Comment: You can look at it on http://www.liteclock.com (it would be more convenient)

Comment: What is the resolution that's causing you issues?

Comment: 1280 x 720 Made the dialog jump

Comment: I would say it's to do with the content making the browser forced to scroll. If you scroll all the way to the bottom, and then click the link.. you'll see it scrolls the page up to the top before it opens the dialogue. Have you spoken to the developer of the dialogue box plugin? As the demo of the plugin seems to work absolutely fine.

Comment: I haven't, but I don't think it's the content since the content never changes but the jump happens after the dialog loads and look OK, so it sounds like a  JS issue, but no CSS changes applied (none that I noticed)

Comment: There's something fishy about the way that the weather and chat boxes are positioned on the page.

Comment: @TomerGal No, the jump happens before the dialogue loads.. and I'm not talking about the content changing, I'm talking about the browser needing to show scrollbars that is affecting the position of the page when the dialogue is opened.

Comment: I set both the weather and chat to `display:none` and then clicked to add an alarm, and since then every time I go to add another alarm the dialogue appears perfectly in the centre of the page.. just for your info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think it's because your chat text-field is focused upon opening the dialog. If the window is too small to show the chat, the browser automatically scrolls down until the message-field is completely visible.

Comment: Thank you! I think that was it, I cannot reproduce the bug anymore after I removed that focus feature and it makes sense to me that this was the bug.